# Is 100 training examples sufficient for training custom NER using spacy?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, spacy

I have trained NER model for names data. I generated some random sentences which contain names of the person. I generated some 70 sentences and annotated the data in spacy's format.

I trained custom NER using both blank 'en' model and 'en_core_web_sm' but when I tested on any string. It is able to detect in very few examples.

Is this number of examples are insufficient?

```
My data looks like this -:

[("'Hi, I am looking for a house on rent for a year. Best Regards, Rajesh',\r",
  {'entities': [(56, 63, 'name')]}),
 ("'Hello everyone, I am Gunjan Arora',\r", {'entities': [(22, 34, 'name')]}),
 ("'Greetings!, I am 34 years old. I want a car for my wife Bella Roy',\r",
  {'entities': [(60, 69, 'name')]}),
 ("'Heyo, I lived with my family comprises 4 people and myself Randy Lao',\r",
  {'entities': [(60, 69, 'name')]}),
 ("'I am Geetanjali. ',\r", {'entities': [(6, 16, 'name')]})]

I have generated some 70 examples like this.

Losses during training -:

 - 1.Losses {'ner': 6.307317615201415} 
 - 2.Losses {'ner': 11.182436657139132}
 - 3.Losses {'ner': 6.014345924849759}
 - 4.Losses {'ner': 6.442589285506237}
 - 5.Losses {'ner': 5.328383899880891}
 - 6.Losses {'ner': 1.706726450400089}
 - 7.Losses {'ner': 3.9960324752880005}
 - 8.Losses {'ner': 5.415169572852782}

These losses when I am using blank 'en' model
```

Please suggest.

I wanted to detect names as the pre-trained model itself is not able to detect names in most of the cases as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for a better result, you will need to generate more examples, 70 examples is not Ok to train your model although it may work on a non-sophisticated problem.
I would suggest to triple your generated examples for a good fit

Comment: Thanks, for the information. Any other suggestion would you like to give. Other methods I can try to detect entities.

Comment: you may want to read this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-review-of-named-entity-recognition-ner-using-automatic-summarization-of-resumes-5248a75de175)