# How many training data(sentences) are required for custom NER using spacy python?[Just rought idea]

Tags: python, machine-learning, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I want to know let's say I have 10 custom entities to recognize how much annotated training sentences should I give (Any rough idea) ??

Thank You, in Advance!! :)

I am new to this, please help

Answer (score 2):

For developing custom ner model at least 50-100 occurrences of each entity will be required along with their proper context. Otherwise if you have less data than your custom model will overfit on that. So, depending upon your data you will require atleast 200 to 300 sentences.

Comment: Thank You @Hitesh Laddha for putting your answer. Is this given somewhere online or you are telling this by your experience

Comment: I have worked on a similar ner project using spacy and tried and tested with different number of sentences. Also, you can refer here for more details -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56330196/is-100-training-examples-sufficient-for-training-custom-ner-using-spacy.

Comment: If you want an annotation tool for your dataset then you can look here - https://github.com/ManivannanMurugavel/spacy-ner-annotator

Answer (score 1):

For the custom NER model from Spacy, you will definitely require around 100 samples for each entity that too without any biases in your dataset.

All this is as per my experience.

Suggestion -:
Spacy Custom model you can explore, but for production level or some good project, you can't be totally dependent on that only, You have to do some NLP/ Relation Extraction, etc. along with this.

Hope this helps.